# Circular name references in bash shell function, but not in ksh

Tags: bash, ksh, variable, function, typeset

I'm writing a set of shell functions that I want to have working in both Bash and KornShell93, but with Bash I'm running into a "circular name reference" warning.

This is the essence of the problem:

```
function set_it {
    typeset -n var="$1"

    var="hello:$var"
}

function call_it {
    typeset -n var="$1"

    set_it var
}

something="boff"
call_it something
echo "$something"
```

Running it:

```
$ ksh script.sh
hello:boff

$ bash script.sh
script.sh: line 4: warning: var: circular name reference
hello:
```

KornShell93 does exactly what I want, but Bash fails, and also warns about the same thing on line 2 if the `something` variable in the script is named `var` instead.

I'd like to have the `var` variable be local to each function, which is why I use `typeset`, but Bash doesn't seem to like "dereferencing" a nameref to a variable with the same name as the nameref itself. I can't use `local -n` or `declare -n` since it would break in `ksh` which lacks these, and even if I did, it doesn't solve the issue.

The only solution I've found is to *use unique variable names in each function*, which seems rather silly since they are local.

The Bash manual says the following about `typeset`:

> `typeset` [...]
>
> `-n`     Give each name the `nameref` attribute, making it a name
>                        reference to another variable.  That other variable is
>                        defined  by  the  value  of  `name`.  All references and
>                        assignments  to  `name`,  except  for  changing  the  `-n`
>                        attribute itself, are performed on the variable referenced by name's value.
>
> [...]
>
> When used in a function, `declare` and `typeset` make  each  name
>                 local,  as  with  the  `local` command, unless the `-g` option is
>                 supplied.  If a variable name  is  followed  by  `=value`,  the
>                 value  of  the variable is set to `value`.

It is obvious that there is something I don't understand about Bash's name references and function-local variables.

So, the question is:  In this case, am I missing something about Bash's handling of name reference variables, or is this a bug/mis-feature in Bash?

**Update**: I'm currently working with `GNU bash, version 4.3.39(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)` as well as with `GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-openbsd6.0)`. The Bash shipped with macOS is too old to know about name references at all.

**Update**: Even shorter:

```
function bug {
    typeset -n var="$1"
    printf "%s\n" "$var"
}

var="hello"
bug var
```

Results in `bash: warning: var: circular name reference`. The `var` in the function *should have different scope* from the `var` in the global scope. This imposes an unnecessary restriction on the caller. The restriction being "you're not allowed to name your variables whatever you want, because there may be a name clash with a (local) nameref in this function".

Comment: Same behavior in 4.4.0(5)-rc2; I'd report this as a bug.

Comment: Actually, it's a known problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048#The_problem_with_bash.27s_name_references

Comment: As a practical solution, consider deploying ksh93 everywhere. It's been open source for years.

Comment: @chepner I reported it to bug-bash last night. Thanks for the wiki reference, I hadn't seen it. The suggestion therein is the same as my workaround (use unique variable names).

Comment: @Gilles I wish I could! :-) This came up when rewriting a small library of ksh93 shell utils so that they would be usable in bash too...

Comment: The bug's still there. Now it warns about lines 2 and 4 in the first case and additionally about line 8 in the latter.

Comment: @tomasz What version of `bash` are you currently looking at?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: @tomasz That's to be expected. We'll see if anything changes in 4.5.

Comment: When's that? And how many similar things hang in the air? I'm asking about the known ones...

Comment: @tomasz I'm not on the bash mailing lists, but I'm sure there's either an issue tracker or list somewhere. I'm also not aware of the release schedule (if there is one). Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chet Ramey (Bash maintainer) [says](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-08/msg00055.html)

> There was extensive discussion about namerefs on bug-bash earlier this
>   year.  I have a reasonable suggestion about how to change this behavior,
>   and I will be looking at it after bash-4.4 is released.

In the meanwhile, I'm resorting to slightly obfuscate the names of my local nameref variables, so that they don't clash within the library nor (hopefully) with global shell variable names.

---

In `bash` 5.0, this is ever so slightly remedied (but not really fixed).  The following is the observed behaviour:

```
$ foo () { typeset -n var="$1"; echo "$var"; }
$ var=hello
$ foo var
bash: typeset: warning: var: circular name reference
bash: warning: var: circular name reference
bash: warning: var: circular name reference
hello
```

This shows that it works, but that there also are are a few warnings.

The relevant [NEWS](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) entry says

> ```
> i. A nameref name resolution loop in a function now resolves to a variable by
> that name in the global scope.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Bash's namerefs are a bit stupid, and they pretty much do what it says on the tin: they reference a *name*.
They don't capture the "identity" of the referenced variable, like pointers and references in most general-purpose
programming languages do.

So if you run `declare -n ref=var`, then using `ref` does a name lookup for the variable `var`, and uses its value.

And if you run `declare -n foo=foo`, then using `foo` does a name lookup for the variable `foo`, and... well, realizes it's a loop, and emits a warning.

Also the variable the reference finds might not be the same variable that existed with the name when the nameref was set.
E.g. consider the script below:

```
$ cat nameref.sh 
#!/bin/bash

var="from main"
declare -n ref=var               # a

echo "main:  \$ref='$ref'"

foo() {
    local var="from foo"
    bar
}

bar() {
    echo "bar(): \$ref='$ref'"   # b
}

foo
```

In line "a", the top level `var` is visible (and you might think you're saving a reference to it), but when `$ref` is used on
line "b", it's the `var` from `foo()` that's visible, and that's what the reference finds.

```
$ bash nameref3.sh 
main:  $ref='from main'
bar(): $ref='from foo'
```

You can get the same within one function too:

```
$ cat nameref4.sh

var=outer
foo() {
    declare -n ref=var
    echo "ref=$ref"
    local var=inner
    echo "ref=$ref"
}
        
foo
```

The first `echo` gets the value from the outer context, while the second gets that just assigned in `foo()`.

As mentioned in Kusalananda's answer, Bash 5.0 fetches the top level instance of the named variable when
facing a loop. But that doesn't help that much, since, well, it still emits the warning, and it doesn't let you reference a variable
from the middle of the call stack if you have multiple nested functions.

---

Ksh is different in this regard. I'm not exactly what it does, but it seems that there, `typeset -n ref=var` resolves the variable from the
immediately outer context, and stores its actual identity. Then again, local variables *in general* are different in Ksh than in Bash,
which may be an issue with complex programs using them, even without namerefs in the mix.