# Need to capture stdout and modify variable by reference from function in bash

Tags: bash

I can easily capture stdout from a function call (in subshell) to a variable with:

```
val="$(get_value)"
```

I can also modify variables (for instance, an array) in a shell *by reference* so to speak in the same shell with something like:

```
function array.delete_by_index {
    local array_name="$1"
    local key="$2"

    unset "$array_name[$key]"
    eval "$array_name=(\"\${$array_name[@]}\")"
}

array.delete_by_index "array1" 0
```

But what I'm struggling to figure out how to do is to do both at the same time, in a clean manner. An example of where I want this is popping a value from an array:

```
function array.pop {
    local array_name="$1"

    local last_index=$(( $(eval "echo \${#$array_name[@]}") - 1 ))
    local tmp="$array_name[\"$last_index\"]"
    echo "${!tmp}"

    # Changes "$array_name" here, but not in caller since this is a sub shell
    array.delete_by_index "$array_name" $last_index
}

val="$(array.pop "array1")"
```

It seems to me like all forms of capturing stdout to a variable require a subshell in bash, and using a sub shell will not allow me the ability to change a value by reference in the caller's context.

I'm wondering if anyone know a magical bashism to accomplish this? I do not particularly want a solution that uses any kind of file/fifo on the filesystem.

The 2nd answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027679/store-capture-stdout-and-stderr-in-different-variables-bash) seems to suggest that this is possible in `ksh` using `val="${ cmd; }"`, as this construct apparently allows for capturing output, but without using sub shells. So yes, I could technically switch to ksh, but I'd like to know if this is possible in bash.

Comment: Your script, it seems to me, has become complex enough that it should have been rewritten in a more powerful language. Do it now, it's not too late!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works in both `bash` (since release 4.3) and `ksh93`. To "bashify" it, replace all `typeset` with `local` in the functions, and the `typeset` in the global scope with `declare` (while keeping all the options!).  I honestly don't know why Bash has so many different names for things that are just variations of `typeset`.

```
function stack_push
{
    typeset -n _stack="$1"
    typeset element="$2"

    _stack+=("$element")
}

function stack_pop
{
    typeset -n _stack="$1"
    typeset -n _retvar="$2"

    _retvar="${_stack[-1]}"

    unset _stack[-1]
}

typeset -a stack=()

stack_push stack "hello"
stack_push stack "world"

stack_pop stack value
printf '%s ' "$value"

stack_pop stack value
printf '%s\n' "$value"
```

Using a nameref in the function, you avoid `eval` (I've never had to use `eval` anywhere in any script!). By providing the `stack_pop` function with a place to store the popped value, you avoid the subshell. By avoiding the subshell, the `stack_pop` function can modify the value of the `stack` variable in the outer scope.

The underscores in the local variables in the function is to avoid having a nameref that has the same name as the variable that it references (Bash doesn't like it, `ksh` doesn't mind, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302578/circular-name-references-in-bash-shell-function-but-not-in-ksh)).

In `ksh` you could write the `stack_pop` function like

```
function stack_pop
{
    typeset -n _stack="$1"

    printf '%s' "${_stack[-1]}"

    unset _stack[-1]
}
```

And then call it with

```
printf '%s %s\n' "${ stack_pop stack }" "${ stack_pop stack }"
```

(`${ ... }` is the same as `$( ... )` but does not create a subshell)

But I'm not a big fan of this.  IMHO, `stack_pop` should not have to send the data to stdout, and I should not have to call it with `${ ... }` to get the data. I could possibly be more ok with my original `stack_pop`, and then add a `stack_pop_print` that does the above, if needed.

For Bash, you could go with the `stack_pop` in the beginning of my post, and then have a `stack_top_print` that just prints the top element of the stack to stdout, without removing it (which it can't because it would most likely be running in a `$( ... )` subshell).

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I could think of without using files or modifying the function was to run the command twice, in which one be ran in a subshell for capturing, then the other to modify the variable in the parent shell.

```
val="$(array.pop "array1")"
array.pop array1
```

If rewriting the function is an option:

```
function array.pop {
    local array_name="$1";
    local last_index=$(( $(eval "echo \${#$array_name[@]}") - 1 ));
    local tmp="$array_name[\"$last_index\"]";
    echo "${!tmp}"; 

    if [[ $2 ]]; then
        eval "$2=\"${!tmp}\""; # magic bashism here 
    fi

    array.delete_by_index "$array_name" "$last_index"; 
}
```

To be ran as `array.pop 'array1' variablename`, which will also initialize the variable even if it does not exist:

```
$ array1=(one two three)
$ array.pop array1 var
three
$ echo "$var"
three
$ echo "${array1[*]}"
one two
```