# Referencing bash array variables from another array

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to write a script to reference multiple arrays from another array which holds these array's variable names.

Here's my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
array1=('array1string1' 'array1string2')
array2=('array2string1' 'array2string2')

array_names=('array1' 'array2')

for a in ${array_names[@]}
do
        for b in ${a[@]}
        do
                echo $b
        done
done
```

I'd like the output to scan through both arrays (from the outer for loop) and print the respective strings in the inner for loop which calls echo. My current output is just showing me:

```
array1
array2
```

I'd be grateful for any pointers regarding this. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just do `for b in "${array1[@]}" "${array2[@]}"; do ...; done`?

Comment: I'd like the number of arrays to be flexible. Therefore, if I add an array later, I would just add it to array_names and let the loop take care of it.

Comment: I think this is a case for indirect expansion. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/what-is-indirect-expansion-what-does-var-mean - but, basically, changing `${a[@]}` to `${!a}` does what you want (I think).

Comment: @parkamark No, that just gives him the first element of each array. And `${!a[@]}` gives a length of the array `a`.

Comment: Yes, changing to `${!a}` is just giving me the first elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Bash 4.3 and later](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare#nameref) supports "name references", or namerefs (a similar concept exists in `ksh93`, but [the scoping is annoyingly different](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302578/circular-name-references-in-bash-shell-function-but-not-in-ksh)):

```
#!/bin/bash

array1=('array1string1' 'array1string2')
array2=('array2string1' 'array2string2')

array_names=('array1' 'array2')

for a in "${array_names[@]}"; do
    declare -n arr="$a"

    for b in "${arr[@]}"; do
        echo "$b"
    done
done
```

The variable `arr` is a nameref that acts like an alias for the named variable (the variable with name `$a` in this example).

Without namerefs, in earlier Bash versions, one solution would be to create a new array that contains all the elements from the other arrays:

```
all=( "${array1[@]}" "${array2[@]}" )
```

... a bit like the `array_names` array in the question but with the contents of all arrays, and then iterate over `"${all[@]}"`.

It's also possible to use `eval`, but the resulting code looks astoundingly awful.

See [glenn jackman's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390766/116858) for a variation with variable indirection (introduced in its current form with Bash version 2).

Answer (score 2):

@Kusalananda has the best answer for recent versions of bash. For earlier versions, you can use an indirect variable:

```
for a in ${array_names[@]}; do 
    tmp="${a}[@]"
    for b in "${!tmp}"; do echo "$b"; done     # or: printf "%s\n" "${!tmp}"
done
```

See the 4th paragraph of https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 0):

As a variation on what's been said:

```
#!/bin/bash

array1=('array1 string1' 'array1 string2')
array2=('array2 string1' 'array2 string2')
array_names=('array1' 'array2')

for (( i=0; i<${#array_names[@]}; i++ )); do

    declare -n arr="${array_names[i]}"

    for (( j=0; j<${#arr[@]}; j++ )); do
        echo "${arr[j]}"
    done

done
```

Accessing the elements by index instead