# how to get the indexes of a referenced array in bash?

Tags: bash, array

here is a sample code

```
astr[10]=a
astr[20]=b
astr[30]=b
astrR="astr[@]"
echo ${!astr[@]} #the indexes
echo ${!astrR} #the values
#FAIL: echo ${!!astrR}

astrR="!astr[@]" # wild guess
echo ${!astrR} # empty output, so I am still wild
```

So, how to get the indexes using `astrR` ?

Comment: I found no question like this one, but I actually just found a way to answer it here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390763/30352, so I thought was good to keep this question.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do with `astrR`? Are you trying to print indices and values of the associative array?

Comment: Can you explain the use-case you are trying to solve?

Comment: I get the array name as a function param, then I need to modify the external array using the reference and keeping the indexes, for that I needed a way to access the external array by it's name (as a not known variable) to maintain it (add, remove items etc)

Comment: Expansions with references in `bash` is not supported directly. You might need to re-consider your design if you are planning to do this bash

Comment: it is already working: `declare -n strR="astr"`, may be I should just delete this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`declare -n astrR="astr"`

from tips here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390763/30352

(answered mainly to not be left as unanswered and calling unnecessary attention from other questions needing it)