# Can I combine ksh/zsh and other shells with Bash in the same workflow?

Tags: shell, session

Can I combine ksh/zsh and other shells with Bash in the same workflow (shell session)?

I am used to Bash but I might need some behavior available either in ksh or zsh. Could I use Bash with them, in a single shell session somehow, at least where they don't clash?

No problem to solve here, just a architecture question to better know relations between shells and for general knowledge.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `ksh -c COMMAND` or `zsh -c COMMAND`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are potentially two questions here:

1. May I write scripts in multiple shell variants and use them together?
2. May I write a script for one shell variant and have it executed by another shell interpreter?

---

For the first question:

Yes, as long as the scripts are executed by the shell interpreters that they were written for. Note that it doesn't matter what shell you use for *interactive* work as long as the scripts have proper `#!`-lines and/or are executed with explicit interpreters (e.g. `ksh myscript`).

A script works just like a command that you (or someone else) wrote. Another script could call it no matter in what language it was written (assuming it is executable and has a correct `#!`-line).

For the second:

If you write your scripts using only the lowest common denominator in terms of  syntax and grammar (which in the case of these three shells is POSIX `sh`), you can be *fairly* certain that they will run under all these shells (but I'm assuming there may be edge cases where one shell's POSIX conformance may be lacking). But why would you have `zsh` or `ksh` run an `sh` script when you just as well could run it with `/bin/sh`?

`ksh93` and `bash` (and possibly `zsh` as well, but I'm not too well versed in that shell) *do offer a fair bit of commonality in their extensions to plain `sh`*, but there are situations where even though the syntax and semantics are seemingly in agreement, [strange issues arises from other differences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302578/circular-name-references-in-bash-shell-function-but-not-in-ksh).

In the general case, no, you can not assume that one shell will be able to successfully and correctly run a script written for another shell. For example, a `bash` script could *use* a `ksh` script just as if it was any other command, but it should never `source` a `ksh` script.

Ideally, you should assume that different shells are completely different scripting languages, and write for a particular shell, just as you would *not* write a piece of Python code and expect it to run under Perl or Ruby (unless it was some contrived [polyglot script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing))).

Comment: [an example polyglot script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stephane-chazelas/misc-scripts/master/which_interpreter)

Comment: ahhh, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71137/117549) was the entry point for that reference

Comment: @JeffSchaller Urrgh...   :-)

Answer (score 0):

As a simplistic example in the affirmative:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ for othershell in ash dash posh rksh bash ksh zsh; 
  do 
    $othershell -c "echo Hello from the $othershell"; 
  done
Hello from the ash
Hello from the dash
Hello from the posh
Hello from the rksh
Hello from the bash
Hello from the ksh
Hello from the zsh
```